# Get documents by several field values

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose

I have an `food` mongodb schema as follows:

```
{
name: 'Pork meat',
category: 'Meat'
}
```

Exists several categories and many items which belong to a specific category.

**I want** to sort items by category like this:

```
{
category: 'Meat', items: [ITEMS_WHICH_BELONG_TO_THIS_CATEGORY]
},
{
category: 'Drink', items: [ITEMS_WHICH_BELONG_TO_THIS_CATEGORY]
},
{
category: 'Souce', items: [ITEMS_WHICH_BELONG_TO_THIS_CATEGORY]
}
```

I have this code:

```
const categories = await Food.find().distinct('category').exec()
const result = []
    for (let i = 0; i < categories.length; i++) {
      result.push({ category: categories[i], items: await Food.find({ category: categories[i] }).exec() })
    }
```

This is good, but can I optimize this code? Can I do this in one query?

Comment: Use `db.collection_name.aggregate(
   [
     { $group : { _id : "$category", items: { $push: "$$ROOT" } } },
     { $sort:{_id:1}
   ]
)`

Comment: `This is good, but can I optimize this code? Can I do this in one query` - Single queries vs multiple queries does not always === better performance, however, having said that answers to this question might be just based on opinion - Also, is this more of a question for [**https://codereview.stackexchange.com**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com)

Comment: @Veeram, you have the best solution, thanks a lot

Comment: @Fran thanks, I'll take into account on future

Answer (score 1):

You can optimize your loop by using map or forEach to do this

```
const result = categories.map((category) => {
   return {
    category,
    items: await Food.find({ category: category }).exec()
}
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Aggregation pipeline for grouping your `Food` items based on `Categories`:

```
Food.aggregate([{
    $group : {
        _id : "$category",
        items : { $push : "$name"}
    }
}],function(err, result){
    //result will have food items grouped by category
})
```

See MongoDB [Aggregation](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/aggregation/) and [$group](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) for more information.